# Issues installing a private google sheets addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

**TL;DR** -> Clicking "Manage Add-ons" now doesn't show private add-ons anymore. It used to be possible to select "use on this document" and to remove the private add-on but now I can't see private addons that are installed.

---

I've published a private google sheets add-on as I've done many times. The access to the add-on is restricted to "Only trusted testers from your developer dashboard".

I've installed the add-on by opening the add-on link with the account of one of these trusted developers, allowing access to the services etc. Until here everything as usual.

I've tried using the add-on by clicking on the "Add-ons" menu and "activating" it as I used to, by clicking on "Manage Add-ons" and selecting "use on this document".

Here you have the add-on installed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TK7Y.jpg

The issue is that the "view" has changed/been redesigned and now I don't see any of my installed private addons, what I see is "You have no G Suite Marketplace Apps installed.".

It used to be like this: https://i0.wp.com/digitalinspiration.com/images/google-sheets-addon.png?resize=1170%2C808&ssl=1

Now this is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXDI1.jpg

The "trusted developer" account I'm referring to is already using private add-ons installed some time ago and those are working fine, hence is clearly false that there are "no Apps installed". I wanted to try to uninstall the add-on and reinstall it but I have no idea how to remove since it doesn't show up anyware. Nonetheless, if I open the link of the private addon, the button to install it is diabled and the label is "installed".

Do you have any idea what the problem is and how I could manage to find a way to "activate" the addon and a way to remove it?

Comment: Are you still having the same issue? I couldn't replicate this.

Comment: Hey @AndresDuarte thanks for the follow up! Yes eventually i've figured out what the problems were. One problem was related to me calling functions in onOpen()  that required Auth.FULL and hence preventing the menu to be created. The second, related to the plugin not showing in the "mange addons" list, is a google's issue. it's apparenlty and intended bahviour they're aware of regarding private addons and they will fix it when they will move the addon puslbishing process entirely to the G suite marketplace.